# How to get the locked heading in Vizzy scripting language?

Tags: juno-new-origins

In [Juno: New Origins (formerly SimpleRockets 2)](https://www.simplerockets.com/), when writing a [Vizzy script](https://junoneworigins.fandom.com/wiki/Vizzy) to control my plane or rocket, how do I get access to the currently locked heading vector (i.e., the vector toward which the autopilot is trying to aim)? There are three commands that can be used to *alter* the heading (by locking the pitch in degrees, heading in degrees, or the whole heading vector), but I can't find any way to *get* the heading that was set by the user.

Note that I'm quite open to using Funk to get this info, but looking at [the recommended documentation](https://wnp78.github.io/JunoXml/InputController), I don't see that input.